# Heat Equation Analysis

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I have a question and I'm not really sure how to get the initial condition from the question. I've managed to determine $U(x,t)$ from $u(x,t) = U(x,t) + \psi(x)$ by modifying the boundary condition to = 0 but I still can't seem to determine the initial condition, which is why I am stuck after $U(x,t)$.

I don't need the exact question but a hint towards finding that initial condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: This is the question]

I understand that the BC are $u(0,t) = 120$ and $u(20,t) = 30$ and the rest is just normal working but the initial condition is bugging me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding of the problem. Let us draw the initial configuration:

[image: config]

Mathematically, this could be written as an initial- and boundary-value problem for the heat equation $\partial_t u = D\partial_{xx} u$. The initial conditions are
$$
u(x,0) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&120 & & \text{if}\; 0\leq x\leq 15\, ,\\
&30 & & \text{if}\; 15\leq x\leq 20\, ,
\end{aligned}\right .
$$
The boundary conditions are $u(0,t)=u(20,t)=30$ for $t>0$.